# iterating is too slow: found faster alternative but 'sqlite3.Row' instead of values

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have a function getMoverList() that needs to SELECT Names from a sorted sqlite3 column:

```
def getMoverList():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT Name, CAST (Points AS int) as Points, FROM table ORDER BY Points DESC')

    moverList = []
    for Name in cur.fetchall():
        playerName = str(Name[0])
        moverList.append(compareRanks(playerName))

    return moverList
    conn.close()
```

The function has to get the Names of the db column, pass each Name to another function compareRanks(playerName) to get a wanted value (RankingDifference) and make another sorted list with wanted values.

The above code works but is pretty slow. I found alternative [Python is slow when iterating over a large list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402033/python-is-slow-when-iterating-over-a-large-list) that makes a way faster list:

```
def getMoverList():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    moverList = conn.execute('SELECT Name, CAST (Points AS int) as Points, FROM table ORDER BY Points DESC').fetchall()
    return moverList
    conn.close()
```

The problem is that moverList now doesnt contain strings with names but 'sqlite3.Row' objects. Tried things like

```
mover = getMoverList()
print (mover[0].Name)
```

but "'sqlite3.Row' object has no attribute 'Name'" How to do this?

Edit: Using sqlite3.row here:

```
def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn
```

Edit2: getLastRank(): Here I pass a player Name to the function and want to have a look at my table for LastRank of previous backupped db. I dont have ranks saved in the db table. Instead I initially worked with flasks loop.index to show rankings and now that I want to work with it I figured out to get a rank with ROW COUNT. If I put conn.close() before the for loop with return I get 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.'

```
def getLastRank(playerName):
    conn = get_db_previous()
    player = conn.execute("SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Points DESC) Rank, Name, Points FROM alltime").fetchall()
    
    for item in player:
        if playerName in item:
            return item[0]
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row

Comment: @Shawn Im using sqlite3.row but not sure if I do it properly. I'll edit my first post and show you the regarded func get_db_connection()

Comment: From the documentation Shawn linked, you can use `mover[0]['Name']` to achieve what you're after. A row apparently behaves like a `dict` with column names as keys and column data as values.

Comment: calling `conn.close()` after `return` is not a good idea ..

Comment: @balderman Can you explain why? In general or because of speeds? I also did not like this but I had one function where it told me it can not operate on a closed database. I reviewed my testing code and found it. getLastRank(playerName) I will edit into OP. I need to restructure all of this. My first thought today was: If I am going through multiple functions best way will be to connect and close to db just once, need to rethink all my project, ty :)

Comment: @joH1: Thank you, that got me the output I was looking for. Unfortunately I still now have to iterate the output Names into the compareRanks(playerName) func and that again felt like as slow as the original solution. Any way to avoid iterating through a list for the function? I feel like the for loop is the speed problem.